# How to constrain a Blob to a specific type

Tags: typescript

Per https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/29becf05012bfa7ba20d50b0d16813971e46b8a6/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts#L641-L646 , I see the definition of `Blob`:

```
/** A file-like object of immutable, raw data. Blobs represent data that isn't necessarily in a JavaScript-native format. The File interface is based on Blob, inheriting blob functionality and expanding it to support files on the user's system. */
interface Blob {
    readonly size: number;
    readonly type: string;
    slice(start?: number, end?: number, contentType?: string): Blob;
}
```

I'd like to constrain this type to insist on a Blob of a particular `type`.

It appeared to me that one might need a [Mapped Type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and/or an [intersection type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types), but particularly as a newb to TS, I'm not clear on whether the examples for a Mapped Type are changing all properties, and how to constrain it properly.

I would have expected I could do something like this:

```
type HTMLBlob = {
  [P in keyof Blob]?: Blob[P];
} & { type: 'text/html' }

function handleHTMLBlob(blob : HTMLBlob) {
  // ...
}

const blob : HTMLBlob = new Blob(['<b>Test</b>'], { type: 'text/html' });

handleHTMLBlob(blob);
```

But the playground reports:

```
Type 'Blob' is not assignable to type 'HTMLBlob'.
  Type 'Blob' is not assignable to type '{ type: "text/html"; }'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"text/html"'.
```

Is there a way I can constrain a property here to a specific subtype (preferably without using generics, if that is possible)? (I also don't want to redefine other properties of `Blob` (besides `type`) since if `Blob` ever gets new properties, I want my Blob subtype to automatically inherit those properties.)

Comment: Blob's `type` is not what you think it is... It's just the Content-type header that will be sent with any HTTP request where this Blob is implied. So `new Blob( [ "hey I'm just plain text" ], { type: 'application/pdf' } )` really just holds the binary data of an UTF-8 plain text file containing the text passed in, it's not a pdf file at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you here. The examples of Blob on MDN use HTML (or JSON) examples similar to mine. I wouldn't expect your example to work when sent somewhere to be processed as a PDF.

Comment: My point is that this `type` parameter is only used in very specific cases, like for instance when you send the Blob though `XHR.send( blob )` it will be used to set the Content-Type header of the request; When you set an iframe's src to a blobURI pointing to the blob, then its type might be used to know how the browser should interpret the content. But in anyway this `type` has no impact whatsoever on the **content** of the Blob, so it makes very little sense to force it to be a fixed value.

Comment: It does if one wishes to introspect on the Blob (type), e.g., for an IndexedDB tool to intelligently show HTML Blob contents in WYSIWYG, JSON with a JSON syntax highlighter, etc.

Comment: I might mention I'm also intending this as a means of documenting functions so that one could introspect on TS files to discover whether the uitlity supports handling such-and-such a Blob.

Comment: Ok you have your reasons (that I don't understand to be honest), just remember that checking for this property tells you **nothing** about the content. So I don't know where you are gathering your Blobs from, but you'll probably have to double check your Blob's content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [extends](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces) keyword.

You want to create a new interface (e.g. `HTMLBlob`) and add the property `type: 'text/html'` to it. You get all properties from your previous interface and can add new ones:

```js
interface HTMLBlob extends Blob {
  type: 'text/html';
}
```

Comment: This gives the same error--because `Blob` already has an existing `type` property (a string) which TS considers incompatible with a string literal extension. (And same result when setting the extension to `readonly` as in the original.)